# Checking of String if it has this specific value

Tags: java, android, string

So I have this problem. I have a string token which looks like this `jdK10ds3` and sometimes with `jdK10ds3TEST`. I want to check if the string has `TEST` starting to the last. I tried using `string.contains()` but it can detect the string when it is on the middle like this `jdK1TESTds3`.

How to check the string if it has `TEST` on the last(ignoring the cases) and how to parse the string to remove the `TEST` on the last. It is possible that the `TEST` can be doubled like this `jdK1TESTds3TEST`.

Comment: If the values are fixed, you can check the string length, instead.

Comment: I don't completely understand the requirement. But you can check if TEST appears to the last and only once with this condition. `if(str.indexOf("TEST") == str.length() - 4))`

Comment: Use indexOf it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is your friend :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String s1 = "jdK1TESTds3TEST";
    System.out.println(s1.replaceAll("(?i)(.*)TEST$", "$1"));
}
```

O/P : `jdK1TESTds3`

The code above replaces the last TEST (if it exists). Add `(?i)` modifier to make it case-insenstive.

Comment: Woudl that also remove the TEST in following string: "jdK10TESTds3"?

Comment: @cherry-wave - No, it wont

Comment: where to add the `(?i)` modifier? show the code pls

Comment: @SecretCoder - EDited my answer.. Please consider doing some research on regex

Answer (score 3):

How about just using: `String.endsWith()`? Make the string upper-case first.

If true, `String.substring()` to `length - 4`

Full code:

```
String string = "jdK10ds3TEST"; // jdK10TESTds3TEST / jdK10TESTds3
if(string.toUpperCase().endsWith("TEST")) {
    string = string.substring(0, string.length() -4);
}
System.out.println(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code checks it "TEST" is part of your inputstring. if it exists removes it and prints the string.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "jdK10TESTds3";
        String test2 = "jdK10ds3TEST";
        boolean status = false;
        System.out.println(test.substring(test.length() - 4, test.length()).equalsIgnoreCase("TEST"));
        System.out.println(test2.substring(test2.length() - 4, test2.length()).equalsIgnoreCase("TEST"));
        status = test2.substring(test2.length() - 4, test2.length()).equalsIgnoreCase("TEST");
        //Remove the test if it exists
        if (status) {
            test2 = test2.substring(0, test2.length() - 4);
            System.out.println(test2);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are asking for ?

```
    package org.app.temputil;

    public class Test2 {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String testString = "jdK1TESTds3TEST";
            System.out.println("Does is end with TEST(ignoring case)?" + testString.toLowerCase().endsWith("test"));
            System.out.println("After removing the last 'TEST' = " + testString.substring(0, testString.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf("test")));

        }
    }
```

**Does is end with TEST(ignoring case)?true**

**After removing the last 'TEST' = jdK1TESTds3**

Answer (score 0):

There is one way to do these is,
How to check the string if it has "TEST" on the last (ignoring the cases)

```
// find all occurrences backward
String word= "TEST";
String text = "jdK10ds3TEST";
i = text.lastIndexOf(word);
```

Now for getting remaining string,

```
String subtext=text.subString(0,i-1);
```

Comment: That wouldn't work if the string would be "jdK10TESTds3"

Comment: Request of OP was to find/remove it only if it is at the end of the word.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
public void checkData()
{
    String resultString = "jdK10TESTds3TEST";

    if(resultString.lastIndexOf("TEST") == resultString.length() - 4)
    {
        resultString = resultString.substring(0, resultString.length() - 4);
        System.out.println("Contains == >" + resultString);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Not Contain");
    }
}
```